# Floated divs with absolute images not clearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In [this link](http://theatresonline.com/theatres/_new-template-theatres/hotels-tname.html), you see a page I am working on. When you change your window size, you will see that it is responsive.

However, the three rotating image boxes that are floated, with height auto and a clearing div under them, are not clearing.

The aim is to have the div containing these rotating images, and 20px padding on both top and bottom of it.

My css currently:

```
.rightbox{width:100%; clear:both; float:none; height:auto; min-height:inherit;}

#rotating-item-wrapper, #rotating-item-wrapper2, #rotating-item-wrapper3 {margin: 10px 20px 0px; float: left; left:0; transform:none; height:auto;}
```

less than 576px:

```
#rotating-item-wrapper, #rotating-item-wrapper2, #rotating-item-wrapper3 {margin: 5px 10px 0px; float: left; left:0; transform:none; width:26%;}

.rotating-item, .rotating-item2, .rotating-item3{width:100%; height:auto;}
```

Comment: It's not recommended to link live sites to reproduce the problem. Create a jsFiddle instead.

Comment: @MelanciaUK not a clue how i do that to replicate it. Use firebug to edit it as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will take you in the right direction: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Answer (score 0):

You can set `height` to `.advertpanel`. Current height of floated element is 0, so clear doesn´t work in this case (you clear after 0) - due to absolutely positioned images in carousel.

For mobile phone, <576px, you can hide that, it´s so tiny and mobile phone users has nothing from that.

Comment: Can't do that, the images change in height to the div needs to change with them. The div also needs to be their permanently as it is premium advertising space.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not you `clear:both`, it's clearing the float but the problem is the floating element's height.

your rotating images is absolute while the container, eventhough it's relative and floating, doesnt get the height of the image inside it. try give a height value (the height of your slideshow image) instead of `height:auto` of the container.

Comment: Again, the container width changes, so do the images. Which means the heights need to be auto, otherwise there will still be the black space that I do not want.

Comment: it's up to you on how you solve it but it's not about clear floats issue, it's about absolute element inside a height:auto element. if you insist with your height:auto for absolute elements inside it, it's useless. just saying

Comment: Fixed it with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with JavaScript.

```
<script>
    var rotating = function(){
    var getheight = $('.rotating-item'); /* cache the selector */
    $('.advertpanel').css({ height: getheight.height() });
    }

    $(document).ready(rotating);
    $(window).resize(rotating);
</script>
```

Comment: Doesn't work without resizing the browser first. Is there something I did wrong?

Comment: yeah mate, your attitude :)

Comment: @bondythegreat just mad that my answer is the correct answer for absolute items in a height auto div...